# Blocking mount syscall

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, syscalls

I would like to block the mount syscall when someone wants to remount `/system` in read-write mode.
Which means i would like to not allow the exection of the following: `mount -o remount,rw /system`.
Anyone has an idea where do i need to look to change the code in the kernel?
I've tryed to look in `/fs/namespace.c` where are some functions related to mount but i am not quite sure.

Comment: don't give rootshell to anyone.

Comment: @IporSircer Yeah, but if by any means someone gets root i would like for him not to be able to do it anyways.

Comment: If he's root, he still can write to any device in /dev, and he can mount your partition elsewhere with rw.

Comment: @IporSircer that's why i want to intervene in the code, if he try's to call mount with specific parameters i am stopping the code execution

Comment: There are also userspace solutions for mounting, and the root has always write permissions on all devices in /dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like SELinux, or `seccomp`, but given that full root privileges allow modifying any partitions without mounting them and doing other nasty things, possibly even loading kernel modules to circumvent the restrictions, it may not be that trivial. At least you'd need a comprehensive ruleset that blocks all the usual holes.

Modifying the `mount` binary or the C library is not a solution, since it's rather simple to call the system call directly, without going through a ready-made binary or even the library.

SELinux and the usual means of compartmentalization and hardening would make it harder to break into root in the first place, which might be useful for other reasons also.

Also, there's the question about what you have on that mount point? If it's something relevant only to this system, then does it matter if someone can modify it? If they gain full administrative access on the machine, they can mess up everything else, leave backdoors in their wake and probably at least destroy the partition in question. If you don't expect to need to modify it, and just want to prevent losing the contents, it would be easier to put it on readonly storage. And to take backups.

If the file system there is used by multiple systems, it's probably mounted over the network. In that case, preventing writes to it is better done on the server side, so it doesn't matter if the kernel tries to make a read-write mount, it will still not work.